# Why does setting (test in assembly) give type error?

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I'm using sbt 0.13.8 and sbt-assembly 0.13.0 in a multi-module project.  Everything works great until I try to turn off tests during assembly.

As instructed in the docs I add the line

```
test in assembly := {}
```

in the settings of one of my modules and get the following error

```
/Users/lanny/work/IdeaProjects/Search/build.sbt:61: error: type mismatch;
 found   : sbt.TaskKey[sbt.File]
 required: java.io.File
      test in assembly := {},
          ^
sbt.compiler.EvalException: Type error in expression
```

I'd be happy to show the results of 'inspect test' but alas, I cannot run sbt without removing the line causing the error.  Here's what I see with the line removed.

```
[info] Set current project to search-hadoop (in build file:/Users/lanny/work/IdeaProjects/Search/)
> inspect assembly::test
[info] Task: Unit
[info] Description:
[info]  Executes all tests.
[info] Provided by:
[info]  {file:/Users/lanny/work/IdeaProjects/Search/}hadoop/*:assembly::test
[info] Defined at:
[info]  (sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin) AssemblyPlugin.scala:32
[info] Dependencies:
[info]  hadoop/test:test
[info] Reverse dependencies:
[info]  hadoop/*:assemblyPackageScala::test
[info]  hadoop/*:assemblyPackageDependency::test
[info]  hadoop/*:assembly
[info] Delegates:
[info]  hadoop/*:assembly::test
[info]  hadoop/*:test
[info]  {.}/*:assembly::test
[info]  {.}/*:test
[info]  */*:assembly::test
[info]  */*:test
[info] Related:
[info]  test/*:assemblyPackageDependency::test
[info]  third_party/test:test
[info]  third_party/*:assemblyPackageDependency::test
[info]  search/*:assembly::test
[info]  search/*:assemblyPackageScala::test
[info]  server/*:assemblyPackageDependency::test
[info]  search/*:assemblyPackageDependency::test
[info]  server/test:test
[info]  hadoop/test:test
[info]  hadoop/*:assemblyPackageScala::test
[info] ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sbt.Keys.test in assembly := {}
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/tree/v0.14.3#setup), for sbt 0.13.6+, add this line to your project/assembly.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.2")
```